# Is it OK to use Kotlin Coroutines and RxJava2 in the same project?

Tags: rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

In the project I am working on, I am using the MVP architecture. In Presenter classes network requests are executed with RxJava2. Is it OK to use Kotlin Coroutines as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

For example, you might want to use coroutines for light-weight async tasks, while using RxJava for getting a stream of items and transforming the stream into another one using complex operations. They are just two different tools and approaches to asynchronous programming.

Comment: I've recently started using both in a project and find myself duplicating code in a DAO or in a Repository that's accessed via coroutines and RxJava.
Is this how it has to be or am I missing something?